# Unable to load rss feed in c# that loads fine in a browser (400 error)

Tags: c#, html, rss, webclient

I'm trying to pull data from an [RSS feed](http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v8/catalog/apps/4aef0ee8-2378-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8?os=8.0.9903.0&cc=GB&oc=&lang=en-GB&hw=520170499&dm=RM-821_eu_euro1_111&oemId=NOKIA&moId=vod-gb&cf=99-1) using 'XMLTextReader'. Although it loads perfectly fine in a web browser, I get a 400 error ("The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.") when I use my code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);
while (reader.Read())
{ //Do something }
```

I've also tried 'WebClient' to no avail.

Can anybody enlighten me as to why it works in a browser but not with my code please?

P.S - it works fine with data in a similar format like [this](http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v3.2/en-US/apps/4aef0ee8-2378-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8?clientType=WinMobile%207.1&store=Zest&store=&store=Nokia)

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody enlighten me as to why it works in a browser but not with my code please?

Maybe the remote website expects you to set the UserAgent. For example:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17";
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe the website expects you to be authenticated in order to call this resource? In this case you will need to send an authentication cookie along with the request. Contact the website administrators for more information on how to consume their API if you are uncertain.

Oh an by the way you have the [`SyndicationFeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class built into the .NET framework exactly for this purpose. Using an `XmlReader` to parse RSS seems quite laborious.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Turns out it was the UserAgent part. It's a rush job which will be upgraded to SyndicationFeed when I have time to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly download it with WebClient and feed it into XmlTextReader that way?

```
var url = "http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v8/catalog/apps/4aef0ee8-2378-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8?os=8.0.9903.0&cc=GB&oc=&lang=en-GB&hw=520170499&dm=RM-821_eu_euro1_111&oemId=NOKIA&moId=vod-gb&cf=99-1";
var data = "";

using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
    data = wc.DownloadString(url);                
}

var reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(data));
while (reader.Read())
{
    //
}
```